# How can I set focus to an object outside of a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have 5 different tables that are bound on a Windows Form and using C#.  One of the tables is a DataGridView.  When I load the form with the following code, the object that I want to have focus is automatic.

```
this.termsTableAdapter.Fill(this.terms_DataSet.Terms);
this.customerTableAdapter.Fill(this.customer_Info_DataSet.Customer);
this.customer_ShipTableAdapter.Fill(this.customer_Info_DataSet.Customer_Ship);
this.customer_MailTableAdapter.Fill(this.customer_Info_DataSet.Customer_Mail);
```

when I add the line to bind the DataGridView, I can't set focus to the control that I would like to set to even with the .Focus() as you see below

```
this.customer_Ship_ContactsTableAdapter.Fill(this.customer_Info_DataSet.Customer_Ship_Contacts);
customerComboBox.Focus();
```

any ideas why the datagridview holds the focus rather than the control that I would like to set?

I can click in the other controls to change the focus but I would like it set at form_Load.

Comment: Thanks Hans for the rapid response. it is the perfect answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Focus will only work when the form is visible, and in the load event, it isn't visible yet.

Try using the Select() method instead:

```
customerComboBox.Select();
```

Comment: Thanks LarsTech for the rapid response. it is the perfect answer